# How do you match a regex group more than once?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

Please see the example below as I'm not sure how to explain my ask.

**What I have**

```
(?<Name>\w+)(?:\slikes\s)(?<Likes>\w+)(?:\sand\s)?(?<Likes>\w+)
```

This will not work because of the re use of Likes group.

I need there to be 1 or 2 or even more likes in a single match.

**Test Data**

> George likes icecream and pie
>
> Paul likes ice
>
> Adam likes apples and bananas
>
> Jessica likes cherries
>
> Juan likes cars
>
> Emily likes violet

**Expected Result**

> Match 1 Group 1: George
>
> Match 1 Group 2: icecream
>
> Match 1 Group 2: pie
>
> Match 2 Group 1: Paul
>
> Match 2 Group 2: ice
>
> etc...

https://regex101.com/r/iJXHrc/1

Comment: If you are using Python, you may use PyPi regex module and enjoy access to `.captures("Likes")`. You do not have access to all captures in JS regex.

Comment: What language are you targetting? The solution for JavaScript and Python may be different.

Comment: The built-in `re` module doesn't support this use case, I don't believe. As @WiktorStribiżew said, look into the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module

Comment: Why not just use unnamed groups and make the last group optional: [`(\w+)(?:\slikes\s)(\w+)(?:\sand\s(\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/iJXHrc/2). Besides, your current regex - even if you'd use dupe names eg in pcre - would [clip off letters on strings without `and`](https://regex101.com/r/iJXHrc/4) because of the optional `(?:\sand\s)?` betwween two word characters.

Comment: `(?P<Name>\w+)\slikes\s(?P<Likes1>\w+)(?:\sand\s(?P<Likes2>\w+)(?:\sand\s(?P<Likes3>\w+)(?:\sand\s(?P<Likes4>\w+))?)?)?`

https://regex101.com/r/6tgz8u/1

Comment: I would advise using this "(?<Name>\w+)(?:\slikes\s)(?<Likes>(?:\w+(?:\sand\s)?)+)".  It will match one "likes" name.  You can then split the likes on "\sand\s" and you'll get a list of what you want.